# How to turn textile table rows readable with e.g. line wrapping or empty lines?

Tags: coding-style, textile

I’m editing a table in textile wiki syntax (e.g. redmine). – The lines are long and completely unreadable.

It seems impossible to

- have empty lines in the source to separate logical table rows
- make a logical table row span multiple lines in the source (e.g. with the following lines carry indentation to distinguish them from the next row)

Is there any trick to do some “source code” formatting on textile table rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get some ideas here:

```
|_. Header 1 |_. Header 2 |_. Header 3 |
|
|
|
|               "link 1":http://www.example.com/1________ <notextile>
   </notextile> "link 2":http://www.example.com/2________
   | second column here
   | row doesn’t end unless you let it end with a pipe |
```

- a `|` on a line by itself does nothing, especially it hinders that the table is going to end (and no empty row is added)
- the `<notextile> </notextile>` avoids real line breaks in the result
- end a row with `|` at the end of the line
- end the table with an empty line
- line breaks are line breaks (in that cell)

This all works in “redmine”.